# Instantiate a IVMInstall in Eclipse JDT with same JRE as Eclipse is using?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm creating a [IVMInstall](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/launching/IVMInstall.html) instance to run a Java program by an external Java VM inside an Eclipse RCP product. Normally one is ok with just getting the 'default JRE', which is a global preference that is stored inside the workspace settings (a distinguished element among the list of available JREs). Now, suppose I don't want to rely on that default, nor on the list, but I want to get the same JRE that is currently running Eclipse. Can that be done?

Comment: I can't see anything that provides an `IVMInstall` for the running JRE. Launches that run in the Eclipse JVM use a different system.